# Docker with a Rails App-Workers not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

So I have a Rails Application that has multiple types of workers. I decided to try and run the rails app with Docker, with a separate image for each type of worker (Resque, DelayedJob, a scheduler, different configurations).  The problem is that the workers with queues (DelayedJob + Resque) are not picking up jobs (using both to rule out the queuing system itself). I can see the jobs enqueued, they're there, but the workers never pick up anything off the queue. If I run a worker off the console, it works just fine.

The images are based on Cedarish-https://github.com/progrium/cedarish

The web workers that are sitting behind NGINX seem to be doing fine, though I have noticed some issues with them sometimes becoming non-responsive after a while but not sure if that's related.

Any idea as to what could cause a worker, run under Docker and successfully connecting to Redis + MySQL, to just ignore the job queue and not pick anything up?

Guessing this has something to do with my Docker configuration...

Comment: Are the worker processes actually running?

Comment: Yes, they're definitely running. Both the logs show no errors, and Resque-Web acknowledges that they exist.

Comment: Can you share you knowledge about making Resque work with Docker ?

Comment: @pak What are you running into with Resque not working? There's nothing special since the Resque worker is just reading off the Redis queue.

Comment: @ScottFeinberg I solved my problem : I was not using the phusion passenger's base image services correctly.

Comment: @ScottFeinberg  Are you running separate docker containers for the app and the workers? Are you deploying them with docker-compose or in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was an operating system problem-Docker was running up to 100% CPU usage and just generally misbehaving.

This was on a GCE instance with Debian 7 with backports.

The following fixed the problem:

```
sudo aptitude install bridge-utils libvirt-bin debootstrap
```

vi /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"

sudo reboot
```